ClosedXML empty string instead of null value while bulk copy C#
I'm bulk copying DataTable into excel file with ClosedXML.
In DataTable not all items have values. When puting it in file it seems that the value in this cells are "" (empty strings) instead of null. When sorting the rows it seems as value.
Does anybody know how to import it so the cells won't be "".
var worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet(dt,"Arkusz1");

worksheet.Tables.FirstOrDefault().Theme = XLTableTheme.None;
worksheet.Clear(XLClearOptions.AllFormats);
worksheet.Tables.FirstOrDefault().SetShowAutoFilter(false)
    .SetShowHeaderRow(false);



You mean exporting, not bulk copying. There's no "null" in Excel either. What do you expect to see instead of an empty cell in Excel? Where's the code that actually calls InsertTable or InsertData ?  And what do you mean by When sorting the rows it seems as value ?

Is the real question perhaps how to sort empty cells in a table first or last? Excel's default behavior is to always sort empty cells last

@PanagiotisKanavos I have added the sorting. Empty cells are treated as a text and not empty. In DataTable this fields are null.

It's not an Excel problem, it's the problem of closedxml's 'AddWorksheet' method. Evidently, it converts null to an empty string. You can look at another library if this issue is critical. Or at least try to use the 'InsertTable' method with a chance it has no such issue.

How is it going?
